# jQuery disable TO date relative to FROM date

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, date

I am working on a project where there are two date fields available that will be used for searching between the dates. What I want to do is when a user chooses a date in the FROM field then all the previous dates in the TO field should be disabled.

Example:

FROM: 2016-03-28
To  : 2016-04-10

Here in the above example suppose I want to search between these two given dates then while choosing a date from the date picker in the TO field all the dates till 2016-03-28 should be disabled and the user must not be able to select them. Please help.

jQuery date picker:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="css/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="css/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script>
$(function(){
    $('.date').datepicker({ format: 'yyyy-mm-dd'});
});
</script>
```

HTML:

```
<div class="form-group col-sm-2">
              <label>From</label>
              <input type="text" name="fdate" autocomplete="off" class="form-control date" style="height:25px;"  value="<?php echo $fdate; ?>" />
            </div>
            <div class="form-group col-sm-2">
              <label>To</label>
              <input type="text" name="tdate" autocomplete="off" class="form-control date" style="height:25px;" value="<?php echo $tdate; ?>" />
            </div>
```

Comment: how? show me an example with my code..

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve it like this:

```
$(function(){
    var dateObject;
    $("input[name='fdate']").datepicker({ 
    format: 'yyyy-mm-dd',
    onSelect: function(dateText, inst) {
     dateObject = $(this).datepicker({dateFormat: 'yyyy-mm-dd'}).val();
     $("input[name='tdate']").datepicker({ 
        format: 'yyyy-mm-dd',
        minDate:    new Date(dateObject),
        });

     }
    });

});
```

Here is the working [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jbbqgxnp/)